# Understanding OPCache behavior

Tags: php, caching, cloudflare

Even tho the website is behind CloudFlare CDN, we decided to use OPCache to reduce the load on server as there are a maximum (peak) of ~400 active users per second (most of the time it's 50-100 u/s).

But most pages have some different data for each user, for example user's dashboard overview, most  of the data is same but it has some different numbers for each user that needs to be up to date.

### My Questions are:

1. Is it wise to use OPCache for such a website?
2. How will it handle pages with unique queries? will it take more RAM (caching multiple pages for each user) than running without OPCache?
3. Will it affect performance on pages such as Signup/Login etc?
4. I [read](https://blog.appdynamics.com/engineering/why-every-php-application-should-use-an-opcache/) that all PHP applications should use OPCache, is that correct?

*P.S. The website is running on PHP 7.3.4*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes it will gain performance improvement
2. If your RAM usage increased and you're concerned with it, you can fine tune memory consumption via `opcache.memory_consumption`
3. Affect meaning they will be faster
4. Yes, there really is no reason to not use OPCache other than edge cases (e.g., when your app's source code changes at a very fast rate or testing).

TLDR: Production code should always have OPCached enabled.

Answer (score 5):

OPcache only caches the internal opcode representation of a PHP script, not its output. The queries performed or the content displayed by the page has no impact on how OPcache will behave.

This caching will improve the performance of all PHP web pages. As such, it should always be enabled on production sites.

Comment: I thought it will cache the output as well, so I was wrong, note taken, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Each PHP script is being compiled at runtime,
It takes time to transform the human readable code into a code that can be understood by the machine.

OpCache is a bytecode cache engine , it will compile the script to bytecode script only once - so you will save time - then the precompiled script is being stored in memory, which should lead to performance boosts in your PHP applications.

What i think you are missing is that the opcache DOES NOT cache the result of the script , but it is just compile the script .

Note this method is not good if the php script it self is changing for each user 
or if it is loaded from -let's say for example- a database

Answer (score 1):

As general view for this approach 
Php caching whatever it was APC cache or opcache or else is amazing strategy this should increase php performance by 50% in general 
As it act as follows 
When php script excuted there's this involve three major steps

1-parse of the script

2-compile of the script

3-output

APC cache or else act as intermediary as it saves php script in the compiled form so php will start in the output stage directly and this will not affect queries but it will increase its speed as query for MySQL or else not just the statement of SELECT or whatever but it involves execution of extensions like PDO so it will become faster

You can classify extension as follows

APC or Xcache  for php 5

In new php version use opcache

All of them have the same principle 
Some developers like APC other like opcache 
As example X-cart the popular shopping platform use xcache .